# Substitue non-capturing groups for regex in XML Schema?

Tags: python, regex, xsd, lxml, xsd-validation

I'm linting my first custom XML Schema and lxml gets caught on the expression representing a tuple such as "10.1,-900":

```
<xs:simpleType name="pair_dec">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="-?\d+(?:.\d+),-?\d+(?:.\d+)"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I've read that this is because there is no support for non-capturing groups. Is this right and is there a work around?

Comment: The regex itself is wrong, you are missing `?`s after the groups.

Answer (score 1):

Mind that in XSD regex flavor:

- Non-capturing groups are not supported, but can be replaced with capturing ones
- `\d` and all other shorthand character classes are Unicode aware, so it is safer to use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`
- A dot must be escaped to match a literal dot

Use

```
<xs:pattern value="-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?,-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?"/>
```